# Why do I get ClassNotPersistableException while running GWT App Engine application in hosted mode?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am randomly getting an org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException when I try to perform a query on the local JDO data store of my GWT/App Engine application. This only happens when I run the application on Hosted mode. When I deploy it to the Google App Engine everything works perfectly.

Stack Trace:

```
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "com.wayd.server.beans.WinePost" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:305)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.getExtent(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3700)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getExtent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1515)
    at com.wayd.server.WinePostServiceImpl.getPosts(WinePostServiceImpl.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:527)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "com.wayd.server.beans.WinePost" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.assertClassPersistable(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3830)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.getExtent(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3693)
    ... 32 more)
```

WinePost class is a very simple JDO persistence capable class:

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class WinePost {

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Persistent
private User author;

@Persistent
private String grape;

@Persistent
private String comment;

public WinePost(final User author, final String grape,
        final String comment) {
    super();
    this.grape = grape;
    this.comment = comment;
}

public User getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(final User author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getGrape() {
    return grape;
}

public void setGrape(final String grape) {
    this.grape = grape;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(final String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getUserNickname() {
    String retVal = null;
    if (author != null) {
        retVal = author.getNickname();
    }
    return retVal;
}

public WinePostModel getWinePostModel() {
    final WinePostModel winePostModel = new WinePostModel(grape, vintage, getUserNickName());
    return winePostModel;
}
```

}

The datastore query is performed by the following method:

```
public ArrayList<WinePostModel> getPosts() {
        final ArrayList<WinePostModel> posts = new ArrayList<WinePostModel>();
        final PersistenceManager persistenceManager = PMF.get()
        .getPersistenceManager();

        final Extent<WinePost> winePostExtent = persistenceManager.getExtent(
                WinePost.class, false);
        for (final WinePost winePost : winePostExtent) {
            posts.add(winePost.getWinePostModel());
        }
        winePostExtent.closeAll();

        return posts;
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am pretty sure there's nothing wrong with your code. The reason you get this error is because of a problem with the Datanucleus enhancer.

If you see this error, quit Jetty and check the console inside Eclipse (you'll need to select the correct console in the little toolbar above the console window). It should say something like:

DataNucleus Enhancer (version 1.1.4) : Enhancement of classes
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for **X** classes. Timings : input=547 ms, enhance=76 ms, total=623 ms. Consult the log for full details

... where **X** is the number of classes it has processed. The number should be equal to the number of 'entity' classed you have defined.

But sometimes, for some reason it will say 0 which is why you get the ClassNotPersistableException error.

To fix, open an entity class and change something (add a space or something) and save. Check the console until it says that it has enhanced all of your entity classes. Then restart the debugger and try again.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and you are right the enhancer in eclipse was not running, when I restarted it worked like charm

Answer (score 5):

Posting for future reference for anybody running into same problem, despite this being an old thread.

I ran into the 'same' problem, and found that my classpath had multiple instances of datanucleus-appengine-1.0.7.final.jar. I got to know this from the log which was prompted when I tried to build my workspace. Here's the log content.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:59)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.(Enhance.java:60)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:57)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.appengine" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/G:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.4_1.3.4.v201005212032/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.4/lib/user/orm/datanucleus-appengine-1.0.7.final.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/G:/WS_Quotemandu/quotemandu/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-1.0.7.final.jar."
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:434)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerBundle(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:340)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensions(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:222)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.registerExtensionPoints(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:153)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.registerExtensionPoints(PluginManager.java:82)
    at org.datanucleus.OMFContext.(OMFContext.java:160)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:172)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:150)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1157)
    ... 7 more

G:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.4_1.3.4.v201005212032/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.4/lib/user/orm/datanucleus-appengine-1.0.7.final.jar

file:/G:/WS_Quotemandu/quotemandu/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-1.0.7.final.jar

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had the same problem and it was solved when I removed the duplicate JDO jars from my classpath. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen something very similar before and it was related to the persistantManager being called by different methods at the same time. This happens 'cause the pm is supposed to be a **single instance** (which is not a **singleton** so you have to manage it yourself).

Conditions could change between the development environment and the production one once deployed, so that could explain also what you're seeing.

The problem was solved by using `synchronized` in the declarations of methods which use the pm.

Maybe it's not your case but you might wanna give it a shot.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if I follow your distinction between a singleton and a single instance.  But the point about not having two open PersistenceManagers is a good one and seems to have been the source of my own difficulties.

Comment: this is a common problem indeed - a singleton has a private constructor and a getInstance method which checks if there is already an instance and returns that if so otherwise creates a new instance. A single instance it's a normal class which is meant to be instatiated only once throughout the application, meaning that some kind of wrapper is needed to make sure you are always using the same. Either that or you use synchronized in the methods that use that given class.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, caused by having 2 versions installed.

First I had installed **Google App Engine Sdk 1.8.8**, then an update came in and eclipse downloaded **Google App Engine Sdk 1.8.9**.

Having the 2 versions caused this error to be thrown. Despite everything compiled well, I didn't realize that datanucleus enhancer console log was warning me about this error on compilation time, just discovered that console existed ;-)

The solution, in my case, was to keep only the newer version removing the old one:

- Right click on porject -> Properties
- Drill down to Google/App Engine
- On the right side, you will see a button link named **Configure SDKs**
- A new window opens showing all SDK versions installed
- Select undesired versions and click **Remove** button

[image]

To ensure the old version (1.8.8) was completely removed:

- Open file explorer `C:\Users\XXX\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_1709980481_win32_win32_x86_64\plugins` where XXX is your Windows user.
- If folder `com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8` exists, delete it!

Now, if you open the datanucleus enhancer console, the class appears successfully enhanced.

[image: datanucleus enhancer console log]

Answer (score 1):

Check for your compiler version. It should be 1.7 or less. It should not be 1.8. I also got the same thing and I changed the compiler, then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
In my case the code was correctly processed during building via maven clean + install, see below the excerpt from the logging:

ENHANCED (Persistable) : nl.jdoexample.model.Product
ENHANCED (Persistable) : nl.jdoexample.model.Book

What went wrong was that when executing (in Intellij) prior to the execution (see for this Run / Debug Configurations) the command 'make' was executed,  thereby removing the enhanced java files. This caused the error to pop up.

Reparation of the problem in Intellij (but can also be done in Eclipse or Netbeans):
- jdo-example
    - Lifecycle:
        - edit configuration (Run / Debug Configurations):
            - jdo-example [install]
                Command line: clean install

- Run / Debug Configurations:
   -Application:
      - Remove 'make' 
      - New execution definition:
          - Name: execute main jdoExample
          - Configuration:
              - Main class: nl.jdoexample.main

In this way the application will not be compiled again before execution, thereby removing the enhanced java files.
This was successful in my situation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

"The class "com.wayd.server.beans.WinePost" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found."

So why not check each of those 3 conditions ? One of them is true.

Comment: I checked them and everything seems to be fine. The app works fine when I deploy it on the App Engine and I get this exception randomly.

Comment: perhaps report a bug? java support is still in "beta"

Comment: If that message appears then one of those 3 things are true. Nothing else it can be. There are bytecode decompilers available to check enhancement. The CLASSPATH can easily be printed out with respect to whether metadata/annotations are present. The log (at DEBUG level) can easily be checked and gives large amounts of information, about what metadata is found.

Comment: -1 The question was asked in good faith.  You've essentially told him to read the manual.

Comment: And the manual is incorrect ? Please provide your evidence that it wasn't, and i'd be happy to update it. As the other reply says, change a class and it gets re-enhanced ... so the class wasn't enhanced. And then you trace back and find that GAE/J plugin for Eclipse is unreliable in detecting when a class is changed.

Comment: Why are you being hostile? A number of people up above gave weird ways in which this problem was solved. While you may be technically correct, there are apparently a miriad of ways in which this can cause this to be true. None of them having to do with the user being an idiot and not defining this as you say. I am also currently running into this problem and have no idea why any of these 3 conditions have been met as everything seems to be correctly defined. You might as well have answered "Is it plugged in?"