# Google AppEngine Eclipse: ormLibs cannot be null

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, datanucleus

I'm currently trying to persist an object of a class using the Google App Engine's PersistentManagerFactory. I'm getting an error that I don't quite understand:

```
 org.datanucleus.api.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: 
 The class "com.google.gwt.sample.vendorcouver.client.user.VenUser" is not persistable. 
 This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file 
 is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-
 Data/annotations for the class are not found.
```

I did everything suggested at [Why do I get ClassNotPersistableException while running GWT App Engine application in hosted mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004968/why-do-i-get-classnotpersistableexception-while-running-gwt-app-engine-applicati) (made sure I had @PersistenceCapable on the class, made sure I don't have any duplicate .jars in my Classpath). Eventually I discovered in my Datanucleus Enhancement console:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: ormLibs cannot be null
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.EnhancerLoader.removeOrmLibs(EnhancerLoader.java:66)
at      com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.EnhancerLoader.getClassPath(EnhancerLoader.java:43)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.EnhancerLoader.<init>(EnhancerLoader.java:37)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:69)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
```

I'm not entirely sure what ormLibs should be, and I can't seem to find much about it online. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See if this thread helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105914/runtime-exception-datanucleus-enhancer

Comment: FYI "DataNucleus" has nothing to do with "ormLibs". The thing that seemingly needs "ormLibs" (whatever that is) is Google's Eclipse plugin; you can see this for yourself in the stack trace ... all Google's code there